# I am not sure on where to start to prove $∀x∈R |x−a|≤1 ⇒ |x+a|≤1 + 2|a|$

Tags: limits, infinity

I don't know if the epsilon-delta definition of limit will help here. $\forall_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ we have $|x-a| \leq 1 \implies |x+a| \leq 1 + 2|a|$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It looks like this inequality could be useful when *applying* the epsilon-delta definition of limit.  I don't see a direct relationship with [tag:infinity]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

By the triangle inequality,

$|x+a|\le|x|+|a|,$

and $|x|\le|x-a|+|a|.$

Answer (score 1):

For all $x\in R$

$$|x-a| \leq 1 \implies |x+a|=|x-a+2a|\leq |x-a|+|2a|\leq 1 + 2|a|$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following triangle inequality:
\begin{eqnarray}
|x|-|y| \le |x-y| \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Suppose $|x-a| \le 1$. Writing:
$$|x-a| = |x-2a+a|$$
call $x+a = z$. Then, by (\ref{1}):
$$|z| -2|a| \le |z-2a| = |x-a| \le 1 \Rightarrow |x+a| \le 1+2|a|$$

Comment: What was your reasoning for getting 1 at the end?

Comment: I have concluded $|z| -2|a| \le 1$ and  $z=x-a$. Thus $|x-a| \le 1 +2|a|$.